# How do I print the help text description above the field for all textareas?

Tags: theming, 8

For all textareas, I want to print the help text description above the field input.

By default, it looks like this:

- Field Label
- Field Input
- Help Description

I want to arrange it like this:

- Field Label
- Help Description
- Field Input

[This was actually a hidden configuration option added to Drupal 8.0](https://www.drupal.org/node/314385)  So, the basic idea is that I have to set `'#description_display' => 'before'` for every textarea.

To do that, I tried to use [template_preprocess_textarea()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_textarea/8.4.x).

I added the following code to `mytheme/mytheme.theme`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_textarea(&$variables) {
  $variables['#description_display'] = 'before';
}
```

I checked to make sure this code is called with `kint()` but it doesn't change the positioning of the help descriptions on the forms.  I checked my theme (Bootstrap's) templates and they have logic for handling `before` and `after`.  So what is the right way to call this to adjust the position of the help text on all textareas?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but have you tried using HOOK_preprocess_form_element instead of preprocess_textarea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `description_display` property is still working if supported by your active theme and I understand it is. Adding this to your `mytheme.theme` should do the trick :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'textarea') {
    $variables['description_display'] = 'before';
  }
}
```

Note that this might not work with formatted fields from the field API as the description field is in a parent template, see `text-format-wrapper.html.twig`. It would be a little more complicated to have this working for those fields.

Comment: If anyone else needs this simple approach, we created a module shell using the hook_preproccess_form_element approach. I set it up as a module instead of a theme hook, as we tend to use admin themes. Feel free to save yourself some time and use/modify/etc: https://bitbucket.org/idfivellc/idfive_move_description/src

Comment: Hi. Will this work on ECK fields ?

Comment: This works great in Drupal 9! However, it doesn't work for Select Other webform fields, as both input elements are in a fieldset with the description after them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for this, which supports Drupal 7,8,9,10+

https://www.drupal.org/project/top_description